# My UserControl Crashes Visual Studio Whenever I Add It To A Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I have written a small [System.Windows.Forms.UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx), call it `userControl1`, that seems to be working the way I want it to.

From within Visual Studio 2010's Designer, I can drag `userControl1` from the toolbar and drop it on a Windows Form that I will call `testForm1`. I can wire-up `userControl1`, and it works as it should.

However, the purpose of `userControl1` is to be able to use it in another [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx), let's call it `userControl2`.

From within Visual Studio 2010's Designer, if I drag `userControl1` from the toolbar and drop it onto `userControl2`, Visual Studio 2010 will crash with no message other than it is restarting.

[image: screenshot]

At this same time, an Application Error is logged in Event Viewer with Event ID 1000:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0965f816
Faulting process id: 0x1580
Faulting application start time: 0x01cd90f84338e443
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 49ddcedf-fcf8-11e1-8016-00248103a942
```

How can I go about trying to debug this error? Should I look at something in `userControl1` or `userControl2`?

A few Notes:

- 1) I can also drag a `userControl2` from the toolbar onto `testForm1`, and it works (i.e. displays) fine both in the VS2010 Designer and when I run the test app.
- 2) I have successfully gone into the Designer of `userControl2` where I declared and set all of the values for `userControl1`, but `userControl1` will not display on `testForm1` when it is run. If I select `userControl1` from within the `userControl2` Properties window in the VS2010 Designer, Visual Studio will crash.
- 3) I am happy to post code, if it helps. Would you prefer the code for `userControl1` or `userControl2`? Though both controls are small, there is still a lot of code (particularly since this error is likely occurring in the Designer, so I'd have to post that, too.

Comment: Run two instances of Visual studio, open this project in both instances and in one of them use ***Attach to process...*** option to the second instance to debug it (*devenv.exe* process). You should then be able to see what the exception is.

Comment: Some of the code in your UserControl runs at design time as well.  That code has a bug, it triggers a StackOverflowException.  A pretty fatal error, that takes VS down as well.  Look for recursive property setters/getters, comment out stuff if you can't find it.

Comment: You guys are great! Like Hans pointed out, I new it had to be something in my code. So, using Lukasz's VS attached to VS, I found where I had declared new variables for the Height and Width so that I could set container properties instead of handling the `Resize` event.

Comment: I've posted my suggestion as an answer. I'm glad it helped :).

Comment: Thanks guys! I had the same problem and it was due to an infinite loop from a property of my user control returning its own value!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems this helped to resolve the issue, so I'm posting it as an answer.

In order to debug your control when used in Visual Studio designer, run two instances of Visual studio and open your project in both instances. Then, in one of the instances use ***Attach to process...*** option and attach to the second instance to debug it (*devenv.exe* process). This way, you should be able to see what the exception is.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio might not be devenv.exe; for me, running Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop, it was WDExpress.exe, if I recall correctly.

Comment: This approach was a lot easier than I expected. My problem turned out to be a versioning issue with a reference to a third party control called from a nested UserControl's Load event.

Comment: I had a similar problem - my UserControl would freeze the designer when loaded.  It turned out a parameter was being set to null, which then loaded my Entity Framework Context, which was waiting on a flag to say another process, which is part of application startup was completed, which would, never happen in design mode.  I checked using your method and realized a 'not' was missing when checking the parameter value. Thanks.

Comment: Lukasz M!!!! you helped me a lot!!! I was overriding OnPrint method and calling this.OnPrint(e) and that was causing an stack over flow exception!  thanks... I changed by   base.OnPrint(e); and everything is working fine now!!!

Answer (score 2):

There likely something in the constructor of your control that is attempting to access another something that isn't available, or is creating an exception that can't be caught by the IDE (StackOverflow, OutOfMemory, etc)

Comment: If Lukasz comes back and posts his comment as an answer, I will mark it as the solution. If he does not, you are welcome to update your post by adding his comment and I will mark yours as the answer.